# Python asyncio - Ejecutar dos tareas al mismo tiempo infinitamente

Tags: python, bucles, asyncio

Estoy tratando de ejecutar dos tareas al mismo tiempo infinitamente. En el código de abajo puede parecer obvio combinar las dos tareas en una ya que tienen el mismo intervalo de ejecución, pero mi objetivo es que sea lo más versátil posible, para poder trabajar, por ejemplo, con dos tareas con diferentes intervalos, o que una de las tareas no dependa de intervalos de tiempo fijos (como un servidor websockets), o simplemente que sean más de dos tareas.

```
import asyncio

async def PrimerIntervalo ():
    while True:
        print ('- Ejecución del primer intervalo')
        await asyncio.sleep (1)

async def SegundoIntervalo ():
    while True:
        print ('- Ejecución del segundo intervalo')
        await asyncio.sleep (1)

asyncio.run (PrimerIntervalo ())
print ('Primer intervalo iniciado')
asyncio.run (SegundoIntervalo ())
print ('Segundo intervalo iniciado')
```

Mi problema es que al ejecutar el primer `asyncio.run` se inicia el primer intervalo correctamente pero el código se bloquea en esa parte. O sea, no inicia el segundo intervalo, ni siquiera muestra el mensaje de inicio del primer intervalo.

¿Cómo pudiera poner en marcha ambos intervalos y mostrar ambos mensajes de inicio? ¿Existirá alguna función que sea idéntica a `asyncio.run` con la diferencia de que al ejecutarla no se detenga en ese punto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objetivo de `run()` es simplemente crear el ambiente necesario y ejecutar la rutina asíncrona entrega. Esto es, puedes correr exactamente una corrutina y la función no retornará hasta que la corrutina termine.

Si quieres lanzar varias corrutinas, debes hacerlo otra corrutina. Hay varias formas de lanzarlas. En este caso usamos `gather()`, que permite lanzar varias y recuperar sus retornos.

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather (PrimerIntervalo (), SegundoIntervalo ())
```

#### Demo

```
import asyncio

async def PrimerIntervalo ():
    while True:
        print ('- Ejecución del primer intervalo')
        await asyncio.sleep (1)

async def SegundoIntervalo ():
    while True:
        print ('- Ejecución del segundo intervalo')
        await asyncio.sleep (1)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather (PrimerIntervalo (), SegundoIntervalo ())
    print("Termino")

asyncio.run(main())
print("Fin")
```

produce:

```
- Ejecución del primer intervalo
- Ejecución del segundo intervalo
- Ejecución del primer intervalo
- Ejecución del segundo intervalo
- Ejecución del primer intervalo
```

que no termina nunca, pues las funciones asíncronas están en un loop infinito.